# curl dentro de outro curl para salvar imagens

Tags: php, libcurl, slim, slimframework

Eu tenho uma api em Slim Framework, dentro do "Serviço A" da api estou usando um curl para chamar o "Serviço B" da api, esse "Serviço B" faz o download de imagens pela url delas usando outro curl, ele roda o "Serviço A" e chama o "Serviço B", ele faz o upsert do "Serviço B" com sucesso e faz o upsert do "Serviço A" com sucesso, só que a imagem vem vázia, parece que o curl  do "Serviço B" não salva a imagem mesmo fazendo o upsert no banco.

Segue exemplo do código:

***"Serviço A":***

```
$app->post('/upsertTeste', function () use ($app, $objReturn) {

    $picture_url = = urldecode($app->request->post('picture'));

    $url = "http://servico.com/table2/salvarImg";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "picture=".$picture_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $return = json_decode($data, TRUE);

    $foto = Model1::updateOrCreate(["id" => $id], ["img" => $return["img"]]);

});
```

***"Serviço B":***

```
$app->post('/salvarImg', function () use ($app, $objReturn) {

    $picture_url = = urldecode($app->request->post('picture'));
    $path = DIR_UPLOAD;
    $uniqid = uniqid().".jpg";

    $savefile = download_image($picture_url, $uniqid, $path);

    $foto = Model2::updateOrCreate(["id" => $id], ["img" => $uniqid]);

});

//função pega no stackoverflow em outro post
function download_image($url,$filename,$path){
    if(file_exists($filename)){
        @unlink($filename);
    }
    $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
    if($fp){
        $ch = curl_init ($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = parse_url($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $result['scheme'].'://'.$result['host']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');
        $raw=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        if($raw){
            fwrite($fp, $raw);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        rename($filename, $path.$filename);
        if(!$raw){
            @unlink($filename);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Se eu rodar só o "Serviço B" ele salva a imagem com sucesso em vez de vir uma imagem vázia.